# WIA microdrivers do not work - why?

Tags: windows, wdk, wia

I wrote a WIA microdriver that currently only produces dummy data - later on it should acquire data from a scanner.

The MicroEntry() and SetPixelWindow() functions are called as expected, then Scan(SCAN_FIRST,...) is called and Scan(SCAN_NEXT,...) is called multiple times.

Then I get an error (message has no special meaning) - both when using "Windows Live Image Gallery" and when using "Windows Fax and Scan". I use Windows 7, 64-bit.

I tried to use the official WIA microdriver example from the Windows Driver Kit. I cannot see which functions are called in which order but I get an error message using both programs, too.

Because the official driver from Microsoft does also not work I think the problem is not in my program but somewhere in the OS.

My questions:

Is there any known reason why these drivers do not work?

Is there any work-around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer myself:

The official example microdriver has a bug! Because I used that driver as template for my own one my driver had the same bug.

The problem is that the last argument of the "Scan()" function is NULL in the SCAN_FINISH phase but the example driver will always write 0 to the location this pointer points to.

I wonder why Microsoft didn't find this bug because it will always lead to an exception in the driver!